# Disconnected + Reconnected Hub, now an external monitor isn't being detected

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display

I frequently have this issue where I disconnect + reconnect my hub and upon reconnecting Ubuntu fails to recognize one of my external monitors (of two). Reconnecting the monitors doesn't help. I switched to using new display port cables and it still happens.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Switching the display mode or whatever with <kbd>Super</kbd> (Windows Key) + <kbd>p</kbd> immediately fixed the issue. No idea why and this setting doesn't appear to be anywhere in the "Displays" Gnome system settings. But, it instantly fixed the issue.